# How to synchronize two PC?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed this instruction here : [LINK](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) to install chony and edit the conf file and on my Ubuntu PC I have included this line to syncrhonize with my embedded computer (where ros is running):

```
 server 192.168.86.26 minpoll 0 maxpoll 5 maxdelay .00
```

But when I type:

```
ntpdate -q 192.168.86.26
```

I get this:

```
15 Jan 01:24:48 ntpdate[4560]: 192.168.86.26 rate limit response from server.
server 192.168.86.26, stratum 2, offset -0.001573, delay 0.03282
15 Jan 01:24:48 ntpdate[4560]: adjust time server 192.168.86.26 offset -0.001573 sec
```

Why it isn't syncronized?

This is my /etc/chrony/chrony.conf file

```
pool ntp.ubuntu.com        iburst maxsources 4
pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 2

# This directive specify the location of the file containing ID/key pairs for
# NTP authentication.
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys

# This directive specify the file into which chronyd will store the rate
# information.
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift

# Uncomment the following line to turn logging on.
#log tracking measurements statistics

# Log files location.
logdir /var/log/chrony

# Stop bad estimates upsetting machine clock.
maxupdateskew 100.0

# This directive enables kernel synchronisation (every 11 minutes) of the
# real-time clock. Note that it can’t be used along with the 'rtcfile' directive.
rtcsync

# Step the system clock instead of slewing it if the adjustment is larger than
# one second, but only in the first three clock updates.
makestep 1 3

server 192.168.86.26 minpoll 0 maxpoll 5 maxdelay .00
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312757/how-to-synchronize-two-pc?/) by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 361 on 2019-01-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on 2019-01-15**:
Could you share your etc/chrony/chrony.conf files on the client and server side?

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2019-01-15**:
@curi_ROS I have updated the answer. Regarding the server side, do I need to add chrony too? I thought only client side is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does your embedded board have internet access? If it does then you can sync it using the NTP servers.

If it does not have internet, and only a connection to the server (master/PC), then on the server side, include these lines in your chrony.conf:

(assuming the clients are in the 192.168.165.x subnet)

```
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
local stratum 8
manual
allow 192.168.165
smoothtime 400 0.01
```

And on the client (embedded system) side include these lines in your chrony.conf:

```
server master_ip_address iburst
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
logdir /var/log/chrony
log measurements statistics tracking
makestep 1 -1  #change time in steps at any point after boot(1 -1) || in 3 sync steps (1 -3)
rtcsync        #real time clock sync
```

Note: Ensure the subnet mask is adhered to when writing the `allow 192.168.165` (for a subnet 255.255.255.0). For a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0 you would write `allow 192.168`.

Once you are done, reboot the system, ssh into it, and type `date` in the terminal. The client should have synchronised with your master/server time.

---

Originally posted by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) with karma: 166 on 2019-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2019-01-16**:
@curi_ROS yes my embedded system do have an internet connection. So do you mean I can use NTP server instead of chrony? I thought Chrony is the NTP server, lol)

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2019-01-16**:
@curi_ROS I have added the lines on both embedded and PC but instead of submask, I wrote a full IP of the embedded as they have different IP (my PC address starts at 193). I rebooted but still not synced. I tried to /etc/init.d/chrony start and got this error on embedded:

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2019-01-16**:
1496 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/chronyd-starter.sh $DAEMON_OPTS (code=exited, s
ESCOC

**Comment by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on 2019-01-16**:
AFAIK chrony requires you to be on the same subnet to synchronise time.But if you have access to an internet connection look for a tutorial on syncing automatically using the ntp server

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2019-01-16**:
@curi_ROS Ok cheers. Also, I found google NTP [LINK](https://developers.google.com/time/guides). It says to remove everything which says word server, do I also need to remove pool?

```
pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
```